# Prevent video output to external screen

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a way to prevent/disable video output to an external screen when playing with MPMoviePlayerController?

Answer (score 0):

If by external you mean airplay you can try the following:

```
[moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:NO];
```

Comment: To my understanding this only disables output through AirPlay.  Is there a way to disable the output when an HDMI or VGA adapter is being used?  Or does setAllowsAirPlay: disable both?